# Vanilla js vs jquery transformation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am little programmer who learning Jquery javascript but never really grasped vanilla javascript (i know I am a naughty programmer). My question is how would I go about replicating this functionality in vanilla JS?

```
if ($('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="masterblaster"]').length > 0) {
            $('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="masterblaster"]').click(function () {
                $('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="id[]"]').prop('checked', $('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="masterblaster"]').prop('checked'));
            });
        }

$('#sqlActionsMenu').change(function () {
            var selected = $(this).val();

            if (selected == 'utf8') {
                $('.runUtf8').show();
            } else {
                $('.runUtf8').hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sadly the people who push this "vanilla JS" term are doing you a disservice. What you're looking for is the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). JavaScript is a *language*. You're using JavaScript whether you're using jQuery or the DOM. Now that you know the term, you should be able to find the various methods and properties you need to use, like `querySelectorAll` and `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

The code -

```
if(document.querySelectorAll('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="masterblaster"]').length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="masterblaster"]').click(function() {
        const el = document.querySelector('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="id[]"]').checked = document.querySelector('form[name="sql"] input[type="checkbox"][name="masterblaster"]').checked;
    })
}
```